# Splitting a single tag over multiple statements

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do the following... Note that "output.push();" does not have an ending div tag. but is separately ended at the bottom "output.push();"

What I've done there does not work. I'm trying to encapsulate everything inside the For loop in a single div and className. How can I achieve this please?

```js
function IterateSectionFields({ props, tabIndex, sectionIndex }) {
      return (
        <div>
          {(() => {
            const output = [];
    
            output.push(<div className="field-group">);
    
            for (var i = 0; i < sectionFieldList.length; i++) {
                //Do some more stuff 
                output.push(<div> A few things </div>);
            }
            output.push(</div>);
    
        return output;
      })()}
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve ? Please add a code sandbox link with all your code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "code sandbox link". I need to encapsulate some outputs in a for loop inside a Div tag. My example is simplified, but the only way I can achieve it is by adding the tags to the output array. So basically I want to separate the div open and close tags in separate output.push statements.

Comment: You can't push a unclosed HTML element to an array in JSX. Push only the contents then add it to a closed div at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can't push `<div>` without closing it to an array. All JSX elements need to be *full*, *closed* tags. React created *html elements*, not code. You can't even convert your JSX to Javascript without having properly matched tags.

Note that `output.push <div>{hello}</div>` actually gets compiled into:

```
array.push( /*#__PURE__*/_jsx("div", {
  children: hello
}));
```

Note the Javascript does not have the concept of "opening" or "closing" tags. Just elements.

To fix your code just add only complete elements to the `output` array, and just move the div to the surrounding HTML.

```
function IterateSectionFields({ props, tabIndex, sectionIndex }) {    
      const output = [];
    
      for (var i = 0; i < sectionFieldList.length; i++) {
           //Do some more stuff 
           output.push(<div> A few things </div>);
      }

      return (
        <div>
           <div className="field-group">
               { output }
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all. That means I can't use push for my scenario. The logic just doesn't work. I eventually resolved it by saving multiple variables and then concatenating them.

Something like this:

```
concatenatedOutput = (
    <>
        {concatenatedOutput}
        <div className="section-group">
            {heading}
            {content}
        </div>
    </>
```